# problem identifying a jquery-ui object

Tags: jquery, user-interface, autocomplete

I have a small problem identifying an item with jQuery. Let me explain better :)

I have a menu that appears when the user clicks on a button. This is working perfectly. Then, I want this menu to go away when the user clicks on any part of the site except on the menu. This is also working great, but with a small problem: in the menu, there is an item that allows the user to choose from an autocomplete list. This list was done using jquery-ui autocomplete. When the user clicks on an item here, the menu disappears (it shouldn't :) ), and I don't know how to make the exception for this, since I don't know how can I grab the item, can I grab it by class? Does it have an id?

I have the following code to identify where the click is being done and proceed (you can see that if menu-button or menu are clicked the menu will not hide). How do I make the exception when the click is made in autocomplete of jQuery-ui?

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if($(event.target).parents().index($('#menu')) == -1 && $(event.target).parents().index($('#menu-button')) == -1) {
        if($('#menu').is(":visible")) {
            $('#menu').hide(500);
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autocomplete `ul` has a class of `ui-autocomplete`.  So you can get it by doing `$(".ui-autocomplete")`.

However, my preferred method for doing what you are trying to do would be to do this:

```
$(".ui-autocomplete").click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   //... and maybe some other stuff
}
```

This basically will stop the click from bubbling up, so it will not trigger the document click.

Comment: works for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/Mk2Zf/   and better yet:  http://jsfiddle.net/Mk2Zf/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can pick up those items by their class.
I think I would change it to be:

```
    $(document).click(function(event) {
        if($(event.target).parents().index($('#menu')) == -1 &&
               $(event.target).parents().index($('#menu-button')) == -1  &&
               $(event.target).parents().index($('.ui-autocomplete-input')) == -1 &&
               $(event.target).parents().index($('.ui-autocomplete')) == -1 ) {
            if($('#menu').is(":visible")) {
                $('#menu').hide(500);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks, but this is not working either... Should I use event.target... etc for a class as well?

Comment: Actually it's working but now the menu doesn't close anymore :)

Comment: got confused, sorry, this doesn't work either, the menu still disappears when clicking on an auto-complete element.